# Runtime error '438' issue accessing activeX controls with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have been searching the internet and cannot seem to find an answer to my issue!

I created a spreadsheet in Excel 2010 that uses ActiveX controls (specifically, text boxes and comboboxes).

I have experienced an issue where when I save the spreadsheet, close Excel, and reopen the file, all of the ActiveX controls don't want to cooperate. I keep getting Run-time error '438' Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class. I have tried to access the OLEObject multiple ways:(See below)

```
Sub ResetSheet()

   Sheets("CoverSheet").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value = "Date"
   Sheets("CoverSheet").OLEObjects(1).Object.Value = "Date"

End Sub
```

Both lines will throw the above run-time error....
However something like this works no problem:

```
 Sheets("CoverSheet").OLEObjects(1).Delete
```

What the heck am I missing?!

P.S. per [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840244(v=office.14).aspx):

```
Sheets("CoverSheet").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value = "Date"
```

should have worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding the code to the sheet "CoverSheet" in VBA editor (instead of VBAProject), and see if you run into this problem again in any of the lines:

```
TextBox1.Text = "Date"
TextBox1.Value = "Date"
```

If you are still running into the same problem, check out this post, and see if the solution there helps:
[Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class - Excel Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367215/unable-to-get-the-object-property-of-the-oleobject-class-excel-interop)

Comment: Id like to try your suggestion but could you clarify what you mean by running it in VBA editor instead of VBAProject? (I didn't realize there was a difference)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In VBA editor, under VBAProject there are 2 folders, Microsoft Excel Objects and Modules. In Microsoft Excel Objects you should see your "CoverSheet" object. Could you paste the code there, as it will allow VBA to know that the TextBox1 you are referring to is in this sheet.

Comment: Ok yes I just checked and that is where my code is currently inside of the Sheet1("CoverSheet") object. 

After looking at the link you mentioned in your answer, that seems to have cleared up my issue. Thanks!